# Unarchive file while reducing size of archive?

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

The dilemma: I have a 10GB archive and a 20GB harddrive. When I go to unzip / unarchive the file the harddrive fills up and the process fails.

Question: On ubuntu server 12.04 / linux is there a way that I can unarchive a file while reducing the size of the archive?

Comment: You cannot modify the size of an existing file in this way.  Changing the size of the archive would require removing the contents of the archive which already requires more then 10GB of data.  You need to increase the overal storage on your server, 10GB is the size of the compressed size, its likely 30-40% larger then that.

Comment: Are you positive that deleting files from an archive requires them to be unarchived first?

Comment: You can extract each file, one by one, then delete the file within the archive.  So I gather increasing the size of the storage is out of the question?

Comment: It is out of the question. And what you just said is exactly the kind of solution I'm looking for. The only question is, how? (without doing it manually)

Comment: The only way I know how to do what you want would be by hand. Are you sure the uncompressed data can even fit on the system. You are looking at 14-15Gb uncompresses of data more then likely plus the compressed data of the largest file. The math just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Assume that it can fit. If this can be done by hand, it must be doable by a script. It seems to me like this would've been a problem someone has solved before.

Comment: Are we talking about hundreds of files in the archive?  If we are talking a few dozen files I would create the script by hand.  You need to know each file name in order to do this of course.

Comment: Are you able to plug in a 16GB USB stick and un-archive the files to the stick, delete the archive, move files from USB to HDD?

Comment: Is this server not networked? Can you extract on another machine and move the files across the network? Your situation is incredibly un-detailed so this causes everyone's imagination to run wild. Please specify all of your constraints and why a simpler answer does not suffice.

Comment: What format is the archive in? Tar?

Comment: If the archive is in **uncompressed** tar then you **might** get away with extracting the last file, then truncating the archive by as much bytes as were removed. It it is in a compressed format then this will not work.

Comment: @Ramhound Hundreds of files making it impractical to do by hand. The names of the files in the archive would need to be fetch programmatically.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No more storage is able to be attached. The server is networked but the network speed is impractical for exporting and re-importing the uncompressed archive. 

The constraints of the problem are as they are stated. A 10GB file that needs to be uncompressed on a 20GB harddrive. There are only 10GB of free space making it, currently, impossible to simply unarchive the 10GB file.

Comment: @AthomSfere bzip2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another solution. It won't let you extract individual files from an archive and reduce its size, but it does let you extract all files reducing the size of the archive as you go:

```
#!/bin/sh

# $1, the first paramter, is the .tar.gz file to unarchive

(
    size=$(wc -c $1)
    offset=0
    bs=4096
    while [[ $size > $offset ]]; do
        dd if=$1 bs=$bs count=1 skip=$offset status=none
        fallocate -p -o $offset -l $bs $1
        offset=$(( $offset + $bs ))
    done
) | tar xz
```

Save this into a file like e.g. `untar_and_destroy.sh` and execute as:

```
untar_and_destroy.sh whatever.tar.gz
```

What this does is give part of the `.tar.gz` file to tar, asks Linux to deallocate that part of the file, and then repeats for the next part. When you are done, `ls -l` will say the `.tar.gz` files has the same size as before, but `du` will report its size as 0. This is because the `.tar.gz` has been made into a sparse file, with the same length as before but as all 0s that don't need to be stored onto disk.

Don't use this in production, or anywhere where having that archive deleted would be bad. This makes the archive unreadable as soon as it starts, so if anything goes wrong, e.g. you run out of hard disk space while extracting, you won't get a second chance to run this.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. If it were possible to not corrupt the archive that would be even better, but I think that might just not be a possibility with my constraints.

Comment: You need `count=1` option in dd, otherwise it will output the whole file on first iteration of the loop, which doesn't free the disk space while running the command. Also, I would rephrase `tar xfz -` to `tar xz`.

Comment: @Zouppen Good points, I've edited those in.

Answer (score 2):

Although it may be impractical to expand your primary storage, perhaps you could extract the file contents to an external storage device.

Alternatively, generate a list of files in the archive, then write a script which extracts some of those. Move those files to the cloud, select another batch to extract, lather, rinse, repeat.

But, every archival app I know of has to have the original archive file intact while it creates a new archive file without what you don't want, so external storage is going to be very, very useful.

Comment: The second solution you offer is more of what I'm looking for. However, moving it to the cloud and back is impractical. This needs to be done in place.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any tools that can do this, and I don't think any of the common archiving formats support this.

One possible solution to your problem would be to keep the archive on a different machine and pipe it over to the machine you want to decompress it onto. For example, you could run this command on the machine with the archive:

```
cat archive.tar.gz | ssh YOUR_SERVER tar xfz -
```

The archive will be streamed to the `tar` process running on the server, which will decompress it without needing the archive to ever be present on the server.

Comment: This suggestion, and all the others like it, is very cool. However, this doesnt address the issue of needing to do it on the machine itself. The network speed of the machine makes it impractical to move such a large amount of data in a timely manner.

Comment: so possibly an archival format that would allow for files to be removed from the archive without needing to make a second copy of the archive would be necessary?

Comment: The only way you could make this work would be by extracting files from the end of the archive, and then shrinking the length of the archive. You can hack the `tar` format to let you do this, but not after it has been compressed. It really wouldn't make much sense to even use an archive in this situation, rather than just the files themselves.